# Browserify, Babel 6, Gulp - Unexpected token on spread operator

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I'm trying to get my Browserify/Babelify/Gulp working in my project, but it won't take the spread operator.

I got this error from my gulpfile:

```
[SyntaxError: /Users/mboutin2/Desktop/Todo-tutorial/src/reducers/grocery-list-reducers.js: Unexpected token (16:8) while parsing file: /Users/mboutin2/Desktop/Todo-tutorial/src/reducers/grocery-list-reducers.js]
```

This is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var babelify = require('babelify');

gulp.task('build', function () {
  return browserify({entries: './src/client/app.js', extensions: ['.js'], debug: true})
    .transform(babelify, {presets: ['es2015', 'react']})
    .bundle()
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error(err);
      this.emit('end');
    })
    .pipe(source('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

I tried to create a .babelrc file, but it do the same thing. And my script works when i delete the spread operator.

This is the file where the Unexpected token occurs (quite simple).

```
import utils from '../utils/consts';

const initialState = {
  itemList: [
    {name: 'Apple', type: 'Fruit'},
    {name: 'Beef', type: 'Meat'}
  ]
};

export function groceryList(state = initialState, action = {}) {

  switch(action.type) {

    case utils.ACTIONS.ITEM_SUBMIT:
      return {
        ...state,
        itemList: [
          ...state.itemList,
          {name: action.name, type: action.itemType}
        ]
      };

    default:
      return state;

  }
}
```

I don't know what doesn't work in this, i read some issues on Github and the setup page on Babel website, but i can't make it work correctly.

Can anyone show me how to handle this correctly? Thank you

Answer (score 168, accepted):

That syntax is an experimental proposed syntax for the future, it is not part of `es2015` or `react` so you'll need to enable it.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread
```

and add

```
"plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
```

into `.babelrc` alongside your existing `presets`.

Alternatively:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-3
```

and use `stage-3` in your presets to enable all stage-3 experimental functionality.

Comment: @MikeBoutin loganfsmyth could you please specify where to specify it as preset? I have the same problem, though I use babelify via cli. Thanks

Comment: Via CLI you need a .babelrc file and the presets are in the plugins page on the babeljs site

Comment: Currently its stage 3! :D

Comment: `npm install --save-dev  babel-preset-stage-3 ` and `presets: ["stage-3"]` did it for me.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue, installed stage-2 plugin and modified my package.json file, which looks like below

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react",
      "stage-2"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just as a side note, some text editors (in my case Mac Notes) will contract `...` into an elepsis entity, which will fail validation, so be aware of that too...

Comment: That's not my text editor. It's just somewhere I occasionally dump blocks of code. :D

Comment: It's worth pointing out that various products, including microsoft products and things like slack, often insert their own special formatting characters (which are often hidden) and/or convert certain characters for appearance. That can be really tricky to spot and can cause you problems...