# How to enable support for spread operator feature in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, spread-syntax

I have .js file running in Visual Studio Code 1.4.0

But when I do this

```
var test = state.selectedStorage.storageItems.map(i => {
          if(i.id != action.payload) return i;
          return {
              ...i,
              qty: i.qty - 1
          }
      });
```

I get an underline under the 3 dots(property assignment expected). When I try to do an `npm start` I get

```
 Unexpected token (134:18)
```

this is my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: "./app/index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./app",
    inline: true,
    port: 3333
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)|\.svg($|\?)/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
   externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  },
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browserify, Babel 6, Gulp - Unexpected token on spread operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745118/browserify-babel-6-gulp-unexpected-token-on-spread-operator)

Answer (score 1):

The [Object rest/spread operator](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) is **not** a part of ES2015. It is however supported by babel using the [required plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).

Comment: Yes. I now have that plugin but still does not stop the ide from actually thinking it is still an error. when I run it is fine. Just Visual studio code does not understand it.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_disable-syntax-validation-when-using-non-es6-constructs

Answer (score 1):

From the Visual Code Studio doc page (in the common questions, the one about React Native):

> React Native examples often use the experimental Object Rest/Spread operator. This is not yet supported by VS Code. If you want to use it, it is recommended that you disable the built-in syntax checking (see below).

Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript

Comment: Oh, just realised your issue is not about VSC, but about Babel. Amit's answer is the correct one then. Mine answers your comment you left to his answer.