# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ... (82:8) in Browserify

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to use the mapActions in **Vuex** as given in [Vuex Actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html)

```
methods:{
            ...mapActions([
                'increment' // map this.increment() to this.$store.dispatch('increment')
            ])
}
```

But, it is giving me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` at `...` . I'm not sure what the problem is and what details I would need to include in the question.

Comment: Please let me see your packages.json. This is an issue related to the ES6 compilation. Are you using browserify or webpack?

Comment: Your question was already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745118/browserify-babel-6-gulp-unexpected-token-on-spread-operator).

Comment: @AntónioQuadrado I have already tried that , but still the same :(

Comment: @AntónioQuadrado I'm using browserify, gulp, laravel-elixr and vueify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your package.json

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 6,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true,
        "modules": true,
        "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
      },
      "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "browser": true
      }
    }
  }
```

and in your gulp file in your laravel-elixir instance check if there's a transformer named babelify in `elixir.config.js.browserify.transformers` and if it exists push into its `options.presets` a string `stage-2`. Here's how I have it in my gulp file:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir')    
if (elixir.config.js.browserify.transformers[0].name === 'babelify') {
        elixir.config.js.browserify.transformers[0].options.presets.push('stage-2');
    }
```

It may differ for you but you get the idea. All this makes browserify compile the assets using the stage-2 features like the object spread operator that wouldn't normally be contemplated.

Answer (score 2):

1:Install the label plugin:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread
```

2:Then fix the .babelrc file as follow:

```
{
    "presets": [["latest", {"es2015": { "modules": false }}]],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```