# Syntax error: Unexpected token on spread operator in React/Express server rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am trying to test locally the example from this [website](https://medium.com/@remarkablemark/server-side-routing-with-react-router-7a2289ad6070). But while running the server (using Visual Studio Code), it gives the error: Unexpected token for the spread operator. After some searching, i also did what this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33745466/8542834) suggested, but to no avail. Can anyone guide me how to get this working? Posting no code, since it is the same as the example on the website.

Additional information:

- react version: 15.6.1
- react-router version: 4.2.0
- react-dom version: 15.6.1
- express version: 4.15.4
- node version: 6

Comment: this tutorial are using outdated libraries. you might want to follow other tutorials, eg: react-router here is like < 3.x.x while you are using the version 4. etc

Comment: @ReiDien I understand, i will have a look into recent tutorials then. Thank you