# Can`t use custom restClient for replacing id to _id. Parsing error: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I`m trying to change restClient to support mongoDB(replace id to _id).

This is documantation https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/FAQ.html#can-i-have-custom-identifiers-primary-keys-for-my-resources. I tried different variants, but with this one it shows "Unexpected token"

[This is the screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esImB.png)

```
const convertHTTPResponseToREST = (response, type, resource, params) => {
        const { headers, json } = response;
        switch (type) {
            case GET_LIST:
                return {
                    data: json.map(resource => { ...resource, id: resource._id } ), // here an error with "...resource"
                    total: parseInt(headers.get('content-range').split('/').pop(), 10),
                };
            case UPDATE:
            case DELETE:
            case GET_ONE:
                return { ...json, id: json._id };
            case CREATE:
                return { ...params.data, id: json._id };
            default:
                return json;
        }
    };


 <Admin
         title="Dashboard"
         restClient={convertHTTPResponseToREST('/api')}>
 </Admin>
```

When I use jsonServerRestClient() it works. Maybe there is other way to change id to _id?

Comment: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33745466/6124657) - admin-on-rest outdated, use react-admin ... use graphql (over/instead rest)

Comment: Property 'restClient' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & AdminProps error is apper on my document. Do you know the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer:

You need to replace:

```
data: json.map(resource => { ...resource, id: resource._id }),
```

by

```
data: json.map(resource => ({ ...resource, id: resource._id })),
```

Note the additional parenthesis around the returned object

Comment: Actually this problem is not connected with the spread operator because this error appears only on that line. And when I changed values everything was ok, but functionality didn`t work properly. This question is more connected with admin-on-rest.

Comment: Edited my answer